Google Analytics UA: How to show the sessions from Google and a specific URL
I'm trying to export historical data from Universal Analytics before its closure. I want to get the sessions that came from Google results and launched 'https://example.com/product/whataver'.
For that, I started:

Reports > Acquisition > All Traffic > Source/Medium > google/organic
(I get a graph with the sessions or the users from Google across the
time)
Secondary Dimension > Page
Advanced Search
Include + 'Page' +
Containing + /product/
However, I get a flat graph. It does not work with
users, with sessions, with 'Matching RegExp' (instead of
'Containing'), with 'Landing Page' (instead of 'Page')

